# User logs out after creating/editing article

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-oauth

I'm new to rails and I made this app to learn.

Link - [Magazine](https://frozen-crag-11892.herokuapp.com/)

So the problem is that when a user creates/edits his/her article and clicks on `Back to all articles`, the user is logged out. This does not happen on a normal Show page. I checked using binding.pry in create and update methods that `current_user` is `nil`. Any idea what is happening?

### sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path
  end

def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

end

### application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user, :current_user_json

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def current_user_json
    user = current_user
    if user
      result = Jbuilder.new
      result.name user.name
      result.id user.id
      result.target!
    else
      user.to_json
    end
  end

  def user_access
    redirect_to articles_path if current_user.blank?
  end
end
```

### articles_controller.rb, only create and update methods

```
def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:article].delete(:id)) rescue nil

  if @article.present? && @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
    render json: {server_message: "Successfully updated Article."}
  elsif @article.present?
    render json: {server_message: "Article could not be updated."}
  else
    render json: {server_message: "Article not found."}
  end
end

def create
  article = Article.new(params[:article])
  article.save ? response = {server_message: "Successfully created Article."} : response = {server_message: "Article not created, please try again."}

  render json: response
end
```

### routes.rb

```
Magazine::Application.routes.draw do
  get "sessions/create"

  get "sessions/destroy"

  root :to => 'articles#index'

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :comments do
    resources :comments
  end

  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

### articles_controller.js, for create and update

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/articles',
    data: {article: $scope.articleForm}
  }).success(function(response) {
      alert(response.server_message);
      $scope.articleForm = angular.copy(articleForm);
  }).error(function(response){
      alert(response.server_message);
  });

$http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: '/articles/'+$scope.single_article.id,
    data: {article: $scope.articleForm}
  }).success(function(response) {
    alert(response.server_message);
  }).error(function(response){
    alert(response.server_message);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is in your logs and what does your page template look like?

It seems when you are doing the form submission from JavaScript it doesn't pick up the form authentication token. Without it this line

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

makes it so that any request except GET which doesn't supply current authentication token throws an exception and drops a session. The latter could be the reason user is logged out when you visit another page.

To figure out if that's the case, try removing this line and see if the issue reproduces.

Comment: thanks, that was it. The CSRF token was not inserted as header in the calls, I've added it and it works fine now :)